# How to return multiple values from a C# WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API Endpoint with the following signatures.

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/some-endpoint")]
 public IHttpActionResult getAll()
 {
 ...
 ...
    return Ok({ firstList, secondList });
 }
```

Now, I want to return two list variables firstList, secondList. How to do that?

Comment: try with `return Ok(new { firstList = firstList, secondList = secondList });` which will return a new object with two properties named `firstList` and `secondList`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Return an anonymous type; all you're missing is the word `new` in your code:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/some-endpoint")]
 public IHttpActionResult getAll()
 {
 ...
 ...
    return Ok(new { firstList, secondList });
 }
```

To rename the properties:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/some-endpoint")]
 public IHttpActionResult getAll()
 {
 ...
 ...
    return Ok(new { propertyName1=firstList, propertyName2=secondList });
 }
```

Why not a Tuple, as advocated in the other answer? If you use Tuple your property name are fixed to the name of the Tuple properties (you'll end up with JSON like `{ "Item1": [ ... ] ...`

Comment: How would you deserialize the anonymous type on client side using JSON?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with [system.tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2) or create a new class or structure like :

```
public class TheClass
{
public TheClass(List<string> f,List<string> l)
{
firstList = f;
secendList = l;
}
public List<string> firstList;
public List<string> secendList;
}
```

and

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/some-endpoint")]
 public IHttpActionResult getAll()
 {
 ...
 ...
    return new TheClass(firstList, secondList);
 }
```

But this class must be on clients to be able to receive and work with it